# OUTPUT Alone 1 key from the array

Tags: php, regex

How to make if `_from` is Alone to `_t`o --- to Select _Alone with the higher ID

Drop else from array

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '8',
    '_from' => '2',
    '_to' => '1',
    'date' => '2018-10-15 15:51:07',
    'message' => 'ccccccxxxxx',
    'read' => '0',
    'feedback' => '0',
    'cnt' => '3',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '6',
    '_from' => '1',
    '_to' => '2',
    'date' => '2018-10-15 15:47:01',
    'message' => 'zzzzzzz1',
    'read' => '1',
    'feedback' => '0',
    'cnt' => '1',
  ),
```

Comment: you want to transform that array of arrays? 
if so - can you provide expected output for given input? I am not sure I understand what you mean to be honest.

Comment: yes; for that particular array of array [[exclude those Who have lower ID in Condition that _from is Equal to _to

Comment: I want to trim _EVERY in the array to 1 Single key Where _from is _to i.e. `  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '8',
    '_from' => '2',
    '_to' => '1',
    'date' => '2018-10-15 15:51:07',
    'message' => 'ccccccxxxxx',
    'read' => '0',
    'feedback' => '0',
    'cnt' => '3',
  ),`

Comment: I just don't understand, sorry, 
If you don't mind, feel free to ask me in polish and I will be happy to help if I will be able to understand :)

Comment: "tam gdzie sa 2 klucze _from rowne _to ---robi jeden klucz z tego z wyzszym ID"

Skoro sa rowne... to zaden z nich nie jest wyzszy?

Comment: ten o Wyzszym iid zostaje z dwoch tylko zawsze

Comment: skoro sa rowne, a tak napisales: "gdzie sa 2 klucze _from rowne _to", to znaczy, ze zaden z nich nie jest wyzszy

Comment: z tym ID wyzszym zostaje danego klucza

Comment: w tym przypadku: `0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '8',`

Comment: Hey, guys, it's English talking site, so please use it instead of Polish

Comment: Sorry @Justinas, it was to get more info about actual issue.

Comment: @matiit And now no one will understand more information about issue except you two...

Comment: @Justinas As you can see, there is an answer now - so people could reason what the question was about from looking at the answer. 
Moreover, there are more than 2 people out there who understand polish. 
Moreover, it's XXI century, one can use google translate or any competitor and get a pretty good idea what discussion was about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have small arrays, It is not a problem to run the algorithm with complexity O(n<sup>2</sup>). But for me better is less clear, but faster algorithm with complexity equals to O(2n)

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'id'         => 12,
        '_from'      => 1,
        '_to'        => 2
    ),
    array(
        'id'         => 13,
        '_from'      => 4,
        '_to'        => 2
    ),
    array(
        'id'         => 14,
        '_from'      => 2,
        '_to'        => 1
    ),
);
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $uniqueRecordKey = $item['_from'].'-'.$item['_to'];
    $oppositeRecordKey = $item['_to'].'-'.$item['_from'];

    //If exists record from the opposite and new ID is greater than previous put
    if (isset($newArray[$oppositeRecordKey])) {
        $newArray[$oppositeRecordKey] = $item;
        continue; //Do not append to the end
    }

    $newArray[$uniqueRecordKey] = $item;
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

https://3v4l.org/0oL2d